# getting the row and column label of the specific data point in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to get the row and column label of the column and row that converges at max_val. Essentially, I am measuring the growth rate from one column entry to another.

```
def find_max(area):
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    data=pd.read_csv('Canada.csv')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    #case insensitive
    prov_lower = province.lower()
    data['province'] = df['province'].astype(str).str.lower()

    #get percent change
    if prov_lower in data['province'].values:
        data=data[data['province']==province]
        df_match_pct=data[data.columns[3:-1]].diff(axis='columns').abs()

        #find max
        max_val=df_match_pct.max()
        max_val=max_val.max()

        #select column and row of max value
        c_r = df_match_pct.iloc[0:9] == max_val and df_match_pct[df_match_pct.iloc[0:9] == max_val]
        #how to get the column and row label of this?

    else:
        raise ValueError()

    return max_val,c_r



find_max('alberta')
```

I expect to get the max value of the difference between column for the data classified as 'alberta' and its corresponding row (specific area location), and the years leading to this change (the two years that recorded the biggest change)

Comment: Could you please explain what is your question? I mean is their an error in the code? or you are getting unexpected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use [`numpy.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```
c_r = [(c, r) for r, c in  np.argwhere(df_match_pct.values == max_val)][0]
```

Or if you need actual index and column labels, use:

```
c_r = [(df_match_pct.index[c], df_match_pct.columns[r]) for r, c in  np.argwhere(df_match_pct.values == max_val)][0]
```

Alternative, you could chain [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`DataFrame.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) method:

```
c_r = (df.eq(max_val).idxmax(1).idxmax(1),
       df.eq(max_val).idxmax().idxmax())
```